# NullPointerException from FileInputStream readObject()

Tags: java

I am trying to load a 2D array from a file. I am able to save it using this block of code:

```
        // Save the array to a file using ObjectOutputStream
        ObjectOutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("savestate.dat"));
            os.writeObject(playingField);
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I then attempt to load the file using this:

```
        // First, load file using ObjectInputStream 
        ObjectInputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("savestate.dat"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Then, read object and cast it as EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][]     
        try {
            playingField = (EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][]) is.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I get a NullPointerException when trying to load it:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.updateGraphicsData(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.updateGraphicsData(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.updateGraphicsData(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.updateGraphicsData(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.updateGraphicsData(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setGraphicsConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setGraphicsConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.initGC(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.initDeserializedWindow(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at EnhancedMinesweeper.actionPerformed(EnhancedMinesweeper.java:316)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

at EnhancedMinesweeper.actionPerformed(EnhancedMinesweeper.java:316)is this line: 
playingField = (EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][]) is.readObject();

I know for a fact that my array is not null. I initialized it as a data member like this:

```
    private static EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][] playingField = new EnhancedMinesweeperTile[10][10]; // initialize a 2D array of Tiles
```

And then later on I initialize each and every element like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            playingField[i][j] = new EnhancedMinesweeperTile(i, j);
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with this? Why can I save it to a file but then I am unable to load it from the file? It is driving me nuts.

Comment: Why did you cut out the error message?

Comment: Either there is another exception before the `NullPointerException`, which leads to `is` still being `null`. If my bet is wrong, check the Serialization methods in  EnhancedMinesweeperTile. More detail can only be told if you add the missing lines from the stack trace.

Comment: The array initializer makes no difference after the assignment, so it can still be null -- if `is.readObject()` returns null.

Comment: i put the full error message. ash, can you please clarify what you mean? i initialize my array before i save it to a file and try to load it, and it works fine until i try to load it.

Comment: Because the full stack trace goes down into java.awt.Component.readObject (the deserializer for the Component class), I'm thinking `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` must either be a UI component (don't serialize these!) or contain a leaked reference to a UI component.  Instead of serializing UI components, try to separate your data from your view, and serialize only the data.

Comment: EnhancedMinesweeperTile extends JButton, is that a problem?

Comment: Probably. I don't know anything about serializing awt components -- apparently it can be done, but it seems like you're going to end up storing a *ton* of extra garbage.  I would have an `EnhancedMinesweeperTileData` or something that you give to the EnhancedMinesweeperTile constructor and contains the state you want to save.  Then put the data objects only in an array and write that to a file.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should probably close the output stream in a finally block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` extends or refers a descendant of `java.awt.Component`. I would call the Serialization implementation in `AWT` and `Swing` "tricky", and that's where the exception happens. My recommendation: **Do not serialize UI classes**. Without seeing the code of `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` it's not possible to tell why there is a `NullPointerException`.

I see that the reason why you save  `EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][]` is that you want to save and load the state of your minesweeper game. A cleaner, less error-prone, more flexible solution is to apply the `MVC - Model View Controller` design pattern. In your case it means to split the `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` class into two classes. One class which cares about the view and control of a tile. And one class which cares about the model, the state. You would then, during serialization / deserialization only care for the model, not the UI.

Besides being less error-prone, a separation of the model from the UI provides decoupling, which in turn has a few advantages.

One is that you change the format of load/save without changing anything about the UI code. The other is that you can change the UI, i.e. from Swing to SWT or JavaFX, without changing anything about the model and the I/O code.

If your `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` already is a model, not UI, then you need to implement `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` in that class in order to *detach* the model from anything about the UI that it knows when you serialize it. Serialization serializes an object-graph, and if `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` knows something of the UI, directly or indirectly, it would get serialized as well. The stack trace suggests that somehow `EnhancedMinesweeperTile` even knows about a `java.awt.Window`.

And finally a small hint about simplifying your I/O code and making it less error-prone.

```
void loadFile() {
    try (final ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("savestate.dat"))) {
        playingField = (EnhancedMinesweeperTile[][]) is.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code has a few advantages. It cannot happen that `is` is `null`. Because it's a small function with a separate name, which in your case you would call from `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`, you see more detail (a well-named function) in the stack trace. And because the function is well-named, no need for any additional comment.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right. I stored all the data I needed to store in a separate class called EnhancedMinesweeperTileData, and i included a data member of type EnhancedMinesweeperTileData in EnhancedMinesweeperTile. by saving just the Data object, i was able to load it back without all the GUI stuff.

Thank you so much I really appreciate your kindness and your amazingly fast response